# Strip out the characters which is non numeric, dashes and pipes

Tags: oracle12c

I am trying to find a solution but somehow i am getting wrong output (referred some online solutions and confusing myself. please advise where i am going wrong.

I need to Strip out any characters that is non-numeric,dash "-" or pipe "|" using plsql.

As an example:
if I need to filter the string `0094-78556232_imk*.ext|4444;` the output should be `0094-78556232|4444`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
    col,
    REGEXP_REPLACE (col, '[^0-9|-]', '') AS col_updated
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `regexp_replace`, especially if performance is important.

Instead use the standard string function `TRANSLATE`. Like so:

```
select col,
       translate(col, '0123456789|-' || col, '01234567890|-') as col_updated
from   yourTable;
```

This translates each character in the `col` value, according to the following scheme: `0` is translated to itself, ...., `-` is translated to itself. Any other character in `col`, which is not in this list already, is "translated" to nothing, since there is nothing for it to be translated to in the third argument to the function. So those characters that are NOT on the list are simply removed from the string.